# s_client verify certificate failed, but browser accept

Tags: ssl, openssl

Add full required information, sorry cannot provide the domain, also because it is intranet use only.

---

Some information about openssl iteself

```
[mocker ~]$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
[mocker ~]$ openssl version -d
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
```

apache related configurations :

```
#==============================
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert      .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl         .crl
SSLCryptoDevice                         builtin
SSLMutex                                    default
SSLPassPhraseDialog                     builtin
SSLRandomSeed                           startup file:/dev/urandom 256
SSLRandomSeed                           connect builtin
SSLSessionCache                         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(67108863)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout      2100
SSLProxyEngine                          On

# Service vhosts
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLEngine on
    #SSLSessionCacheTimeout  2100
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/common/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/common/server.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/common/server_intermediate.pem
    Include conf/conf/xxx.conf
</VirtualHost>

#==============================
```

openssl configuarions

```
#==============================
#
# OpenSSL example configuration file.
# This is mostly being used for generation of certificate requests.
#

# This definition stops the following lines choking if HOME isn't
# defined.
HOME                    = .
RANDFILE                = $ENV::HOME/.rnd

# Uncomment out to enable OpenSSL configuration see config(3)
# openssl_conf = openssl_init

# To use this configuration file with the "-extfile" option of the
# "openssl x509" utility, name here the section containing the
# X.509v3 extensions to use:
# extensions            =
# (Alternatively, use a configuration file that has only
# X.509v3 extensions in its main [= default] section.)

[openssl_init]
# Extra OBJECT IDENTIFIER info:
oid_section = new_oids
alg_section = algs

[ new_oids ]

# We can add new OIDs in here for use by any config aware application
# Add a simple OID like this:
# shortname=Long Object Identifier Name, 1.2.3.4
# Or use config file substitution like this:
# testoid2=OID2 LONG NAME, ${testoid1}.5.6, OTHER OID

[ algs ]
# Algorithm configuration options. Currently just fips_mode
fips_mode = no

####################################################################
[ ca ]
default_ca      = CA_default            # The default ca section

####################################################################
[ CA_default ]

dir             = ../../CA              # Where everything is kept
certs           = $dir/certs            # Where the issued certs are kept
crl_dir         = $dir/crl              # Where the issued crl are kept
database        = $dir/index.txt        # database index file.
#unique_subject = no                    # Set to 'no' to allow creation of
                                        # several ctificates with same subject.
new_certs_dir   = $dir/newcerts         # default place for new certs.

certificate     = $dir/cacert.pem       # The CA certificate
serial          = $dir/serial           # The current serial number
crlnumber       = $dir/crlnumber        # the current crl number
                                        # must be commented out to leave a V1 CRL
crl             = $dir/crl.pem          # The current CRL
private_key     = $dir/private/cakey.pem# The private key
RANDFILE        = $dir/private/.rand    # private random number file

x509_extensions = usr_cert              # The extentions to add to the cert

# Comment out the following two lines for the "traditional"
# (and highly broken) format.
name_opt        = ca_default            # Subject Name options
cert_opt        = ca_default            # Certificate field options

# Extension copying option: use with caution.
# copy_extensions = copy

# Extensions to add to a CRL. Note: Netscape communicator chokes on V2 CRLs
# so this is commented out by default to leave a V1 CRL.
# crlnumber must also be commented out to leave a V1 CRL.
# crl_extensions        = crl_ext

default_days    = 365                   # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30                    # how long before next CRL
default_md      = sha1                  # which md to use.
preserve        = no                    # keep passed DN ordering

# A few difference way of specifying how similar the request should look
# For type CA, the listed attributes must be the same, and the optional
# and supplied fields are just that :-)
policy          = policy_match

# For the CA policy
[ policy_match ]
countryName             = match
stateOrProvinceName     = match
organizationName        = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

# For the 'anything' policy
# At this point in time, you must list all acceptable 'object'
# types.
[ policy_anything ]
countryName             = optional
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
localityName            = optional
organizationName        = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits            = 1024
default_md              = sha1
default_keyfile         = privkey.pem
distinguished_name      = req_distinguished_name
attributes              = req_attributes
x509_extensions = v3_ca # The extentions to add to the self signed cert

# Passwords for private keys if not present they will be prompted for
# input_password = secret
# output_password = secret

# This sets a mask for permitted string types. There are several options.
# default: PrintableString, T61String, BMPString.
# pkix   : PrintableString, BMPString.
# utf8only: only UTF8Strings.
# nombstr : PrintableString, T61String (no BMPStrings or UTF8Strings).
# MASK:XXXX a literal mask value.
# WARNING: current versions of Netscape crash on BMPStrings or UTF8Strings
# so use this option with caution!
# we use PrintableString+UTF8String mask so if pure ASCII texts are used
# the resulting certificates are compatible with Netscape
string_mask = MASK:0x2002

# req_extensions = v3_req # The extensions to add to a certificate request

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                     = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default             = GB
countryName_min                 = 2
countryName_max                 = 2

stateOrProvinceName             = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default     = Berkshire

localityName                    = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default            = Newbury

0.organizationName              = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default      = My Company Ltd

# we can do this but it is not needed normally :-)
#1.organizationName             = Second Organization Name (eg, company)
#1.organizationName_default     = World Wide Web Pty Ltd

organizationalUnitName          = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
#organizationalUnitName_default =

commonName                      = Common Name (eg, your name or your server\'s hostname)
commonName_max                  = 64

emailAddress                    = Email Address
emailAddress_max                = 64

# SET-ex3                       = SET extension number 3

[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword               = A challenge password
challengePassword_min           = 4
challengePassword_max           = 20

unstructuredName                = An optional company name

[ usr_cert ]

# These extensions are added when 'ca' signs a request.

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
# the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.

# This is OK for an SSL server.
# nsCertType                    = server

# For an object signing certificate this would be used.
# nsCertType = objsign

# For normal client use this is typical
# nsCertType = client, email

# and for everything including object signing:
# nsCertType = client, email, objsign

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
nsComment                       = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
# deprecated according to PKIX.
# subjectAltName=email:move

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

#nsCaRevocationUrl              = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
#nsBaseUrl
#nsRevocationUrl
#nsRenewalUrl
#nsCaPolicyUrl
#nsSslServerName

[ v3_req ]

# Extensions to add to a certificate request

basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

[ v3_ca ]


# Extensions for a typical CA


# PKIX recommendation.

subjectKeyIdentifier=hash

authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always

# This is what PKIX recommends but some broken software chokes on critical
# extensions.
#basicConstraints = critical,CA:true
# So we do this instead.
basicConstraints = CA:true

# Key usage: this is typical for a CA certificate. However since it will
# prevent it being used as an test self-signed certificate it is best
# left out by default.
# keyUsage = cRLSign, keyCertSign

# Some might want this also
# nsCertType = sslCA, emailCA

# Include email address in subject alt name: another PKIX recommendation
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# Copy issuer details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

# DER hex encoding of an extension: beware experts only!
# obj=DER:02:03
# Where 'obj' is a standard or added object
# You can even override a supported extension:
# basicConstraints= critical, DER:30:03:01:01:FF

[ crl_ext ]

# CRL extensions.
# Only issuerAltName and authorityKeyIdentifier make any sense in a CRL.

# issuerAltName=issuer:copy
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always

[ proxy_cert_ext ]
# These extensions should be added when creating a proxy certificate

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
# the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.

# This is OK for an SSL server.
# nsCertType                    = server

# For an object signing certificate this would be used.
# nsCertType = objsign

# For normal client use this is typical
# nsCertType = client, email

# and for everything including object signing:
# nsCertType = client, email, objsign

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
nsComment                       = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer:always

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
# deprecated according to PKIX.
# subjectAltName=email:move

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

#nsCaRevocationUrl              = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
#nsBaseUrl
#nsRevocationUrl
#nsRenewalUrl
#nsCaPolicyUrl
#nsSslServerName

# This really needs to be in place for it to be a proxy certificate.
proxyCertInfo=critical,language:id-ppl-anyLanguage,pathlen:3,policy:foo
#==============================
```

error message

```
#==================================================
[mocker ~]$ openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -CAfile ca.cert
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 ..../O=xxxx/OU=yyyy/OU=For Intranet Use Only/CN=example.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 ..../O=xxxx/OU=yyyy/OU=For Intranet Use Only/CN=example.com
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 ..../O=xxxx/OU=yyyy/OU=For Intranet Use Only/CN=example.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:....../O=xxxx/OU=yyyy/OU=For Intranet Use Only/CN=example.com
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
 1 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
..............
ca.cert's
content
.............
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=FI/ST=Finland/L=Espoo/O=Nokia Solutions and Networks/OU=NSN IT/OU=For Intranet Use Only/CN=beisop60.china.nsn-net.net
issuer=/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4973 bytes and written 319 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID:     session ID here
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:  Master-key here
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    Start Time: 1392946292
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
#==================================================`
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that `openssl` is unable to locate the certificate of CA. Check the CA folder mentioned inside `openssl.cfg` and copy the certificate there. Now, it should work.

Comment: I can also add the path in the command with -CApath, while still the error put!

Comment: Try -CAfile parameter.

Comment: have tried, still error, I am interested why browser accept the certificate, while openssl doesn't.

Comment: Because, root certificates are installed in browser certificate store.

Comment: so you mean the root certificates in browser may be different with that in server? is there any way to export the related certificates of one site from browser?

Comment: Root certificates are not different. They may not present in OpenSSL CA's folder. You can export from the browser. For this, you need to refer to the help page of browser.

Comment: there are three related files on server: server.key, server.crt, intermediate.pem,  how can I verify the correction of them?

Comment: (I just attach the apache related config lines in the question)

Answer (score 0):

According to your dump, you need the `CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5`. You can get that from [VeriSign Root Certificates](https://www.verisign.com/repository/root.html) and [Licensing and Use of Root Certificates](http://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=roots). In particular, you want the [Root 3 VeriSign Class 3 Primary CA - G5](http://www.verisign.com/repository/roots/root-certificates/PCA-3G5.pem) download.

Once you have the root, supply it to `s_client` via the `-CAfile` option:

```
 openssl s_client -CAfile PCA-3G5.pem -connect www.verisign.com:443
```

The command will produce the expected results:

```
$ openssl s_client -CAfile PCA-3G5.pem -connect www.verisign.com:443 
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = "(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN = VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06, CN = VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
verify return:1
depth=0 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3 = US, 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2 = Delaware, businessCategory = Private Organization, serialNumber = 2158113, C = US, postalCode = 94043, ST = California, L = Mountain View, street = 350 Ellis Street, O = Symantec Corporation, OU = "Infrastructure Operations  ", CN = www.verisign.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware/businessCategory=Private Organization/serialNumber=2158113/C=US/postalCode=94043/ST=California/L=Mountain View/street=350 Ellis Street/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Infrastructure Operations  /CN=www.verisign.com
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
 2 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
---
Server certificate
...
Start Time: 1392895826
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

---

Just bike shedding here, but this could be improved upon:

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP
```

Perhaps the following cipher suite list would be a bit better for you and visitors. There's no need for SSLv2, low security ciphers and export grade ciphers. In addition, it removes RC4 (vulnerable for use in SSL/TLS) and MD5 (well below its theoretical security levels).

```
HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!ADH:!MD5:!RC4:!SRP:!PSK
```

SRP and PSK are actually preferred cipher suites because they provide mutual authentication. But they are rarely used so there's no need to advertise them.

Comment: could you take a look at my answer, there I add some attachments

Comment: If trusting the Verisign root did not work, then we need to see the actual server certificate. Can you provide the website? The server certificate served by Apache should have *two* certificates. First should be the server's certificate. Second should be the intermediate certificate `VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA`. Both are PEM encoded, and its a simple concatenation.

Comment: I am very sorry I cannot provide the certificate cause some reason, could you please tell me how to verify the "concatenation" of them are right or false. I also put the question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.openssl.users/SB8rhvNQ2DI) with the full detail.